# Getting the right dependency version when using a .NET Standard library in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

Consider the following scenario:

1. You have a project "X" in your solution targeting netstandard20.
2. Project X has a dependency on an external nuget package "ENP" which has different versions for netstandard and netframework. When you add ENP to project X, you get the netstandard version.
3. You have a project "Y" in your solution targeting .NET Framework 4.7. This project references project X, and therefore also needs to reference ENP. But if you add ENP as a nuget package to this project, you will get the .NET Framework version rather than the .NET Standard version and your application will crash.

As far as I know there's no way to force nuget to get the correct version. Is the only solution to manually add the correct reference?

Now, a second scenario: you want to distribute project X through a nuget package. When people install it, they will also install the dependency ENP automatically. How do you make sure that nuget grabs the correct version? You can't really ask other people to manually add the right dependency...

Is the correct solution here to have multiple build targets for project X?

Comment: Unless project **Y** has an immediate dependency for **ENP** you shouldn't be including the NuGet reference - let **X** do that for you.  Otherwise the problem you are describing is no different to a scenario where a .NET application depends on multiple DLLs and 3rd party libs and two of them just happen to have explicit bindings to different versions of say _log4net_.

Comment: ...now assuming that **Y** _does_ have an immediate dependency on ENP then the problem you describe is similar to something I ran into with a UWP project.  The solution there was first to add an explicit reference to the 3rd party NuGet package (even if this library was included in other NuGet packages I was about to add) to all projects before adding other NuGet references.  This ensured that the version I wanted was used rather than the other NuGet libs dictacting it

Comment: Y does not have an immediate dependency, but "letting X do it" does nothing. The files aren't copied over on compile.

Comment: _"...The files aren't copied over on compile..."_ - hmmm that's unusual

Comment: Why would Y crash just because it uses the .NET Framework version of the assembly instead of the .NET Standard? It sounds to me like either ENP in not well authored (the assemblies for different TFMs should be API compatible). If that's out of your control, then you need to make X multi-target both netstandard2.0 and net47 and use `#if NET47` `#else` to compile different code in your own package depending on the TFM and ENP's API for each TFM. From what I read, NuGet is working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

> This project references project X, and therefore also needs to
>   reference ENP.

If your project doesn't have immediate dependency on ENP, your project actually doesn't need to reference ENP. Like what **MickyD** and **Zivkan** commented above, nuget is working as designed in your scenario.

For the behavior you met `Y does not have an immediate dependency, but "letting X do it" does nothing. The files aren't copied over on compile`, I think this may because your current project doesn't use `PackageReference` format.

There exists two formats to manage nuget packages, `Package.config` and `PackageReference`. All `.net standard and .net core` projects are using PackageReference format while projects that target `.net framework` can use [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) or [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) format. If your .net framework project chooses `packages.config` to manage nuget packages, after build we can't find files from `ENP` package cause current project and referenced `X` project doesn't use same manage format. For this, create a new project that uses packageReference, or add this into your current project's(packages-config) project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure this project and referenced X project use same `PackageReference` format, then you would find "letting X do it" does what you need for you.

I think above script would resolve your first issue, and then we don't need to continue on your second scenario which is based on first issue. Hope it helps :)